# Paypal Refund/Cancel Order auto refund

Tags: php, api, paypal, return

I've been searching about this and everyone seems to say that to refund, you must go to paypal website, etc. then the customer will issue a refund there.

What I need is this:
When the customer wants to refund, an approval will be sent to admin in my website, then when the admin approves, the admin will, inside the website, select the amount of money to payback the customer. (Then I guess, it will direct to paypal and type the email and password?)

Is this possible? That every process is in my website except for the paying? I didn't seem to find solutions, I don't have any lead also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely Possible,

First of all do make a refund request you must store **Paypal's Transaction ID**

Once Your admin clicks refund approval button

```
var refundTransactionRequestType = new RefundTransactionRequestType
{
    Version = RefundTransactionRequestVersion, //it must be same version with Express Checkout Request Version
    RefundTypeSpecified = true,
    TransactionID = transactionId //HERE You need to set Paypal's TransactionID
};


var refundTransactionRequest = new RefundTransactionRequest( 
            _customSecurityHeaderType, //CustomSecurityHeaderType will have your paypal merchant credentials
            new RefundTransactionReq //Your RefundTransactionRequestType
            {
                RefundTransactionRequest = refundTransactionRequestType
            });

RefundTransactionResponse refundTransactionResponse;


try
{
    PayPalAPIInterface apiInterface = new PayPalAPIInterfaceClient();
    refundTransactionResponse = apiInterface.RefundTransaction(refundTransactionRequest);
}
catch (FaultException err)
{
    return 123123;//Error CODE
}
```

The Code is for C# but it will have the same logic

[Here is reference for RefundTransaction SOAP](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_SOAP/)

[Here is reference for RefundTransaction NVP](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: I've yet to learn C#, so do you mind if you explain it in php? I'm searching all over the net and have not found any tutorial, same question (except for the paypal documentation which is hard for me)

Comment: are you going to use SOAP or NVP, I can help you with PHP integration

Comment: I don't see clearly the difference between the two, I guess either one's fine as long as I have the option to input the amount. Thank you very much

Comment: Here is the basic refundtransaction for php https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-php/blob/master/Merchant/sample/code/RefundTransaction.php